# Can I create multiple pages at once using WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

I am new to WP-CLI and having trouble finding examples of what I want to do.  I know how to create a single page.  `wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Contact'`

Is there a way to create multiple pages with a single command?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways. As mentioned, [`post generate`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/generate/).

```
wp post generate --count=10 --post_type=page --post_date=1999-01-04
curl http://loripsum.net/api/5 | wp post generate --post_content --count=10
```

You could write your own [custom command](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Commands-Cookbook#anatomy). See the [List of community commands](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/List-of-community-commands) for examples or the [package index](http://wp-cli.org/package-index/).

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements example command.
 */
class Example_Command extends WP_CLI_Command {

    /**
     * Prints a greeting.
     * 
     * ## OPTIONS
     * 
     * <name>
     * : The name of the person to greet.
     * 
     * ## EXAMPLES
     * 
     *     wp example hello Newman
     *
     * @synopsis <name>
     */
    function hello( $args, $assoc_args ) {
        list( $name ) = $args;

        // Print a success message
        WP_CLI::success( "Hello, $name!" );
    }
}

WP_CLI::add_command( 'example', 'Example_Command' );
```

And [WPTest.io](http://wptest.io) is a good example of using the [`import`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/import/) command to create test content from xml.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# WP Test - WP-CLI Quick Install Script
# http://wptest.io/
#
# Note: This script assumes you have wp-cli installed.
#####################################################################################

# Ask user where WordPress is installed.
printf "Please provide the local path to your WordPress install: "
read WPPATH

# Import WP Test data.
cd $WPPATH
curl -OL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/manovotny/wptest/master/wptest.xml
wp import wptest.xml --authors=create
rm wptest.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just chain them up using the && operator. E.g:

`wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Contact' && wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Home' && wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Another Page' ...`

Answer (score 1):

After looking further I found a page on the site.  It looks like you can.

```
wp post generate --count=100 --post_type=page --post_date=1999-01-04 curl http://loripsum.net/api/5 | wp post generate --post_content --count=10
```

http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/generate/